# Tesseract OCR QT errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, segmentation-fault, tesseract

I'm making a large-text recognizing program. I'm trying to use Tesseract in multithreaded mode (up to 50 threads).
Sometimes when I am debugging my program I get an error (Segmentation Fault) on this line:

```
/// Returns true if the edge spot in this location is occupied.
inline bool edge_occupied(EDGE_REF edge_ref) const
{
    return (edges_[edge_ref] != next_node_mask_);
}
```

In the file ...\tesseract-ocr\dict\dawg.h

I am creating each instance of tesseract in every thread like so:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *text_ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

if (text_ocr->Init(NULL,"eng",tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT))
{
    qDebug() << "fail to init tessract in the thread" << _id;
    return;
}
```

I'm using Tesseract 3 dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of that error, after i started to use the new qt 5.2.0 with msvc2012 so i used pre-built tesseract 3.02 (msvc) binaries for win32. Actually, still if you create too many same tesseract instances, application will just crash.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check variables "edges_","edge_ref","next_node_mask", it's may be modified in other threads in same time and modification will caus segfault. If you get segmentation fault, you can see callstack of other threads, and usage of this variable in other threads.

Comment: here the variables                                                                   `edge_occupied : "{bool (EDGE_REF, const tesseract::SquishedDawg * const)} 0x4a309b <tesseract::SquishedDawg::num_forward_edges(long long) const+11> bool (EDGE_REF, const tesseract::SquishedDawg * const)"`                                                   `next_node_mask_ = "18446744073709550592"`      `edges_ = "0"`

Comment: Is it actually a right method to use tesseract like this? Or should i maybe use one instance and synchronize it with mutex?

Comment: also `edge_ref = "<optimized out typedef>"`

Comment: Try implement mutex protected methods for accessing this variables

Comment: ok i made it like this using global mutex     `DataStore::ts_mutex.lock();
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *OCRbase = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

        if (OCRbase->Init(NULL,"eng",tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT))
        {
            qDebug() << "Не удалось инициализировать tesseract";
            return;
        }
DataStore::ts_mutex.unlock();` and it still fail with the same error i create my mutex like that 
`class DataStore
{
public:static QMutex ts_mutex; ...`